# PHP removing an object from array returns empty array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

```
$cart_array = .....;

Array
(
[0] => item Object([id] => 123 [size_id] => 2)
[1] => item Object([id] => 123 [size_id] => 3))



$cart_array = array_filter(
    $cart_array,
    function ($item) {
        return $item->id != 123 && $item->size_id != 2;
    }
);
```

**Expected result :**

```
Array
    (
    [0] => item Object([id] => 123 [size_id] => 3))
```

But this returns an empty array($cart_array). Any help would be appreciable.Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because both items in `$cart_array` fail the test.

```
<?php

$cart1 = new StdClass;
$cart1->id = 123;
$cart1->size_id = 2;

$cart2 = new StdClass;
$cart2->id = 123;
$cart2->size_id = 3;

$cart_array = array_filter(
    [$cart1, $cart2],
    function ($item) {
        // Items both have an id of 123, therefore this returns false
        return $item->id != 123 && $item->size_id != 2;
    }
);
```

Maybe you wanted to just keep size 3?

```
$cart_array = array_filter(
    [$cart1, $cart2],
    function ($item) {
        // This will keep $cart2 since it has an id of 123 and a size_id not equal to 2 but remove $cart1 since size_id is equal to 2
        return $item->id == 123 && $item->size_id != 2;
    }
);
```

Example here: http://ideone.com/oqz16S

Comment: But it does not work with below scenario.
http://ideone.com/eK2BMP
What if I need to remove $cart3 ??

Comment: It still works fine for me: http://ideone.com/aJ6X6w, this only keeps `$cart2` because `size_id` fails on `$cart1` and `id` fails on `$cart3`.

Comment: $cart3 id is 124.

Comment: Do you want to keep `$cart3` or remove it? My code removes it and your comment above asked what to do if you want to remove it.

Comment: what I only need is to remove the given item which is related to "id" and "size_id" keep the rest .

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does, if you want a better example you need to provide more use cases. Basically the function needs to return `true` to keep the item and `false` to remove it. Right now out of the 3 carts only `$cart2` is kept because it's `id` matches and the `size_id` does not which makes the function return true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146348/discussion-between-sjdaws-and-madushan-perera).

Answer (score 0):

What is the result if you print_r your array? If the the code you've put in your question is identical to the code you're trying to run, one of your issues is there is no comma (,) between your array items, and there needs to be. Like so:

```
Array
(
[0] => item Object([id] => 123 [size_id] => 2),
[1] => item Object([id] => 123 [size_id] => 3)
)
```

I'm not familiar with the 'item Object(...' syntax you're using, so I won't be of much help past what I've already said.

Also, like the answer above, your test excludes both objects because id on both is 123.